# How to extract data from returned Tasks in an async method in c# in Windows 10

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library, task, windows-10

How to extract the data from the returned value of `getResponseFromUrl` in below `foreach` loop:
Here i am unable to extract the data from returned value.
I am building an app in windows 10 universal app development.

```
var response = NetworkingCalls.getResponseFromUrl(url, requestDictionary);

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> item in response)
{              
     Util.debugLog(item.Key.ToString(), item.Value.ToString());
}
```

This is model code which returns the dictionary

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;
using Windows.Web.Http;

namespace App2.WrittenLibraries
{
    class NetworkingCalls
    {
        public async static Task<Dictionary<string, object>> getResponseFromUrl(string urlString, Dictionary<string, object> requestDictionary)
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            Uri url = new Uri(urlString);
            var requestToSend = JSONParser.getJsonString(requestDictionary);
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, new HttpStringContent(requestToSend,
                                                                                             UnicodeEncoding.Utf8,
                                                                                             "application/json"));
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                try
                {
                    var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();       
                    client.Dispose();
                    return JSONParser.getDictionary(responseString);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    client.Dispose();
                    return new Dictionary<string, object>();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                client.Dispose();
                return new Dictionary<string, object>();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't ever ever do `catch (Exception ex)` - it's a bad programming practice.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion , I would me more helpful if you suggest other good ways to do so.

Comment: @javvajikiran - Simply don't catch `Exception` - only ever catch specific exceptions that you know could occur there that you can recover from. Otherwise don't catch them at all. Your code currently hides errors and makes your code buggy and hard to fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `await` the task in an `async` method:

```
async Task FooAsync()
{
    var response = await NetworkingCalls.getResponseFromUrl(url, requestDictionary);

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> item in response)
    {              
         Util.debugLog(item.Key.ToString(), item.Value.ToString());
    }
}
```

If you're method can't be `async` you can get the result with `task.Result` or `task.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` but that should be a last resort as it blocks the calling thread synchronously instead of waiting asynchronously:

```
void Foo()
{
    var response = NetworkingCalls.
        getResponseFromUrl(url, requestDictionary).
        GetAwaiter().
        GetResult();

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> item in response)
    {              
         Util.debugLog(item.Key.ToString(), item.Value.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: App got struck after implementing in this way.

Comment: The answerer mentioned two different approaches.  You'll need to specify which approach you used.  If you used the second approach, you probably have a deadlock.  Use "await" inside of all "async" methods.

Comment: Thanks alot it worked :) 1st method